# Got a low solve error, but 3d markers are not aligned to the 2d track points in the footage?, not even close?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, video, tracking

So I'm trying to track a *vertical video* shot on my *phone*, with image sequence. Successfully tracked it with 10 track points, and checked each point manually and they're visually perfect or atleast good in my view. Then, solved it with putting in my own A and B keyframes and checked everything under *refine*. Also typed in the sensor width of my cam. And I got a solve error 0.49px.
[image: Screenshot of my tracked & solved footage]

Then I clicked the **Setup Tracking Scene** button and it created the scene in 3d viewport. But the 3d track points(which looks like empty) are not aligned to the track points of my footage.
[image: Camera view]

I tried solving it again and the solve error was same. But the 3d markers wasn't changing. The 3d markers were moving so different from the track points when I played the footage in motion tracking window.
[image: Those red dots are 3d markers]

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in Blender 3.3 LTS version and I found out the reason. Blender doesn't do well with vertical videos for some reason.

I just put black bars on either side of it to make it 16:9 and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Refining the optical center, focal length and radial distortion can sometimes do that. So try solving without some of those and figure out which one is causing the issue.